# Making module name a variable

Tags: python, variables, module, save

I'm new to programming and I'm making a small game as practice. A thing that I would like to implement is saving character's attributes as variables in an executable .py file and then to import that as a module to use those variables.

The problem is that I would not like to hard-code the savefiles' names (so to give the player freedom to choose a savefile's name and to have multiple savefiles without them overwriting each other).

So is there a way to basically make the module name a variable? Or perhaps there's an easier way of going about this.

Comment: You might want to use an actual serialization mechanism for saving values to disk, rather than trying to write out executable Python files. Perhaps the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html) library could be of help? `json.dump(my_dict, file_obj)` will save the contents of a dictionary named  `my_dict` into the file object (from `open()`) named `file_obj`, and then you can read them back out again with `json.load(file_obj)`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll need to research json but it does seem like a very viable option.

Answer (score 0):

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module(module_name, package=None)
```

where `module_name` would be the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - You want to store attributes of a character and want to be able to retrieve them later is that right?

The way to do is to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Where you can serialize an object and store it to a file and later load it again. eg. If you've those attributes as a dictionary - you can do something like following

```
import pickle
x = pickle.dumps({'speed':100, 'agility':200})
char = pickle.loads(x)
```

Note: All objects are not 'pickle'able - read the above document.

With regards to your original question - yes a module can be attributed to a variable simply as follows

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs4
```

or

```
import BeautifulSoup
bs4 = BeautifulSoup
```

But I don't think that's what you are specifically looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your advice. I'll have to study Python a bit more before I can get to pickling since when I tried reading the pickle doc I just got overwhelmed and couldn't understand much. 
But at least now I know what to look for! Thanks again